# Type Word With Just Click Button

Tags: java, android, hotkeys

I don't know if that possible in android or what 
but how to type word by just click on button 
example 
Button 1 = "Hello"
 but i want it typed on keyboard 
it's like hot key
ii have tried  Key Event but i didn't recognized how does it work like if i want Button  To Type Hello automatically on keyboard even keyboard is hidden

```
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to type a word in an `EditText` when you press a button? If so you can just append your text to the `EditText` in your `onClick` method:

```
public void onClickHello(View view) {
    mEditText.append(mHelloButton.getText().toString());
}
```